# Photoshop curve adjustments in Direct2D

Tags: c#, image-processing, colors, rgb, direct2d

For my image processing application, i use Photoshop tutorial to give effects to images using Direct2D and C#. Now i trying to get the equivalent value of Photoshop Curve color(rgb) in direct2d or in C#.

[Photoshop curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHfat.png)

I am trying to pass the Input value as X and Output value as Y into direct2d rgb color. How can i get this thing done..?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to do this in PhotoShop? In Direct2D? What are you "trying to pass the Input value as X and Output value as Y" to? To code you wrote? We need to see it.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explain. I m trying to do this in Direct2d, please see this link [Photoshop Curves](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bHfat.png). In that, i am trying to pass the Input(bottom textbox) and Output(left side textbox) value into direct2d RGB color.